Problemas de instalación en Ubuntu 24.04
estoy teniendo problemas para la instalación de paquetes .deb en Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, aparecía un mensaje de "error: no hay una aplicacion instalada para los archivos "paquetes de debian"", buscando encontré que se podía a través de Gdebi, sin embargo, al intentarlo la PC se cuelga y reinicia. ¿Me pueden ayudar?.

AskUbuntu is an English only site and does not support other languages. Please translate into English

Using Google Translate, I understand that you need an application to install .deb packages and that gdebi hangs your system.
You can use apt to install .deb packages using the syntax below:
sudo apt install '/full/path/to/package.deb'

For example
sudo apt install '/home/yourUserName/Documents/package.deb'

